# How to access html variable passed to html in js?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django

I have a variable 'devices' which i use in a html page by passing it to views.py:

```
def viewsFunction(request):
    devices = getDevices(request)
    return render(request, 'l2l3vpn/l3vpn.html', {'devices': devices})
```

I want to access the devices list to use in JS file like:

```
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), devices);
```

so how to get devices list in the js file?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "html variable".

Comment: Use ajax request from your Django Html template instead of trying the above.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `devices` are JSON serializable you could convert it to a json and then parse in template js code

something like

```py
import json

def viewsFunction(request):
    devices = getDevices(request)
    return render(request, 'l2l3vpn/l3vpn.html', {'devices': devices, 'devicesJSON': json.dumps(devices) })
```

and in template you should have something like

```html
<script>
  const devices= JSON.parse('{{devicesJSON}}')
</script>
```

then you'd be able to use devices js var in the js if your script is included afterwards

or you could simply put if into a hidden input and parse it from there

```html
<input type="hidden" value={{devicesJSON}} id="myInput" />
```

this way you should be able to get it using

`const devices = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("myInput").getAttribute('value'))`

Comment: I tried using it but I found the following error in console: VM325:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: if you'll post template, and view code I can try to help